# The method readAllBytes() is undefined for the type InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I cannot get rid of The method readAllBytes() is undefined for the type InputStream error.
I assume this caused because of the version I use ?
JDK compliance 1.8
Please advise thank you.

```
if (http.getResponseCode() == 200) {                    
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();           
            try (InputStream inputStream = http.getInputStream()) {
                String jsonContent = new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonContent);
                String Stytch_user_id = node.get("user_id").textValue();
                Object[] objects = getUserLogin(Stytch_user_id, "P0002","123456789");
            }       
        } else { 
            System.out.println("failed");
        }
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. The method was introduced in Java 9.  So what do you want to be advised about?

Comment: [`readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()) was added in Java 9, so says the **documentation**, aka the javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`readTree(Reader r)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.io.Reader)) overloaded method to let Jackson read the stream for you:

```java
JsonNode node;
try (Reader in = new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    node = mapper.readTree(in);
}

String Stytch_user_id = node.get("user_id").textValue();
Object[] objects = getUserLogin(Stytch_user_id, "P0002","123456789");
```